# How to deduce Intersection and Difference of these languages?

Tags: regular-language, context-free-grammar

$\mathcal{L1}=\{a^nb^n c^m d^m\;|\;m,n>=1\}$

$\mathcal{L2}=\{a^nb^n \;|\;n>=1\}$

$\mathcal{L3}={(a+b)^*}$

How to deduce the Intersection of $\mathcal{L1}$ and $\mathcal{L2}$ is CFG or Regular?

Also $\mathcal{L1}$-$\mathcal{L3}$ is CFG or Regular language? Can anyone clarify both the questions?

Answer (score 4):

The first and second languages are both context-free but not regular (the second one is a very standard example of a non-regular language).  The intersection of these two languages is empty, since there is no word which is both of the form $a^nb^nc^md^m$ and $a^nb^n$ with $m\geq 1$.  The empty language is regular (just use an automaton with no accept states).

As for the second question: well, none of the words in $\cal{L}1$ are in $\cal{L}3$, since words in $\cal{L}1$ all contain $c$s and $d$s as well as $a$s and $b$s.  So $\cal{L}1 - \cal{L}3 = \cal{L}1$.

Comment: My second question is whether L1-L3 is regular or CFL  language?

Comment: The set difference of L1 and L2 language.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just realised that from the edited title of your question, which I hadn't noticed before.

Comment: Could you please let me know whether I've answered your question or whether there's anything you still don't understand?

Comment: Could you please clarify me that L1-L3 is  CFG or Regular language?

Comment: Well, I told you that it is the same as L1, and I told you what kind of language L1 is.  Do you understand why L1 is context-free and not regular?

Answer (score 1):

$L_1−L_3=L_1$ and $L_1$ is a context-free language. If you know what PDA accepts $L_2$, then you can find a PDA for $L_1$ easily, since  $L_1$ is concatenation of $L_2$ and  $L={{c^n d^n: n>=1}$. PDA for L would be similar to the one for  $L_2$, you just need to replace ***a*** by ***c*** and ***b*** by ***d***.